# Using empty() to adjust output with multiple variables

Tags: php, if-statement, textarea, is-empty

I have two primary variables that are composed of strings and other variables. I want the two primary variables only to be `echo'ed` if all the variables that they are comprised of have data.

The two primary variables are `$introduction` and `colortxt`.

`$introduction` is comprised of `$finalvehicle3`, `$bodystyle`, `$mileage`, and `$hi`.

`$colortxt` is comprised of `$model`, `$exterior`, and `$interiorspec`.

If any of the secondary variables are empty, I don't want the primary variable to be displayed.

Below is the code I have created that doesn't seem to be working. I have been using `empty()`.

My PHP:

```
<?php

 $finalvehicle3 = "Toyota Camry";
 $bodystyle = "sedan";
 $mileage = "30,000";
 $hi = null;
 $model = "Camry";
 $exterior = "red";
 $interiorspec = "black cloth";

 if (empty([$finalvehicle3, $bodystyle, $mileage, $hi]) == true){
  $introduction = "";
  }
 else {
   $introduction = "I am pleased to present this ".$finalvehicle3." ".$bodystyle." with ".$mileage." miles.";
  }

  if (empty([$model, $exterior, $interiorspec]) == true){
   $colortxt = "";
  }
  else {
  $colortxt = "This ".$model." is finished in ".$exterior." with a ".$interiorspec. " interior.";
  }

  echo "<textarea name=''  id='' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>";

    echo  $introduction." ".$colortxt;

  echo "</textarea>";
  echo "<br><br>";



 ?>
```

In this case `$introduction` should not be displayed as `$hi = null`

Comment: You're building an array full of data and then asking if it's empty? The answer will be no. Check each variable individually.

Comment: **A:** Only `isset()` can accept multiple arguments with comma separated values, not `empty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get `empty([$finalvehicle3, $bodystyle, $mileage, $hi])` to work.

I was able to use:

```
if (empty($hi)
     || empty($finalvehicle3)
     || empty($bodystyle) 
     || empty($mileage)){
  $introduction = "";
 }
else {
   $introduction = "I am pleased to present this ".$finalvehicle3." ".$bodystyle." 
                    with ".$mileage." miles.";
}
```

Will that not work?

Comment: That is because only `isset()` can accept multiple arguments with comma separated values, not `empty()`. That is the real answer here.

Comment: ^ very cool, I didn't know isset() could accept multiple vars. ty.

Comment: You're welcome :) Check out the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and now you know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if both variables are not empty echo them out:

```
if (!empty($introduction) && !empty($colortxt)) {
    echo  $introduction." ".$colortxt;
}
```

---

As a side, while coding style has personal preference, where you set these variables seems awkward as you *set them to empty based on a condition*, but logically (my logical at least) is to instead preset them to empty and *add data if the data exists*.

INSTEAD of your code here:

```
if (empty([$finalvehicle3, $bodystyle, $mileage, $hi]) == true){
  $introduction = "";
  }
 else {
   $introduction = "I am pleased to present this ".$finalvehicle3." ".$bodystyle." with ".$mileage." miles.";
  }

  if (empty([$model, $exterior, $interiorspec]) == true){
   $colortxt = "";
  }
  else {
  $colortxt = "This ".$model." is finished in ".$exterior." with a ".$interiorspec. " interior.";
  }
```

Do this:

```
$introduction = "";
$colortxt = "";

if (!empty([$finalvehicle3, $bodystyle, $mileage, $hi]) == true) {
  $introduction = "I am pleased to present this ".$finalvehicle3." ".$bodystyle." with ".$mileage." miles.";
}

if (!empty([$model, $exterior, $interiorspec]) == true) {
  $colortxt = "This ".$model." is finished in ".$exterior." with a ".$interiorspec. " interior.";
}
```

Just looks cleaner to me :)

I'd also not create a new array to check multiple variables, and would do:

```
if (
    !empty($finalvehicle3)
    && !empty($bodystyle)
    && !empty($mileage
    && !empty($hi)
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify (not intended to take away from the other answers); only `isset()` can accept multiple comma-separated values, and not `empty()`.

The manuals state:

on [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> bool empty ( mixed $var )

on [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

> bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

Therefore you need to separate and check if each value is empty.

I.e.:

```
if(empty($var1)) && empty($var2)){}
```

Or using the `||` (OR) logical operator depending on what you want to check for; if any or all are empty.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

**Note:**

What you used here:

```
if (empty([$finalvehicle3, $bodystyle, $mileage, $hi])  == true)
```

*theoretically* would be a "false positive".

If anything, you will need to use the `== true` in a separate statement.

I.e.:

```
if(empty($var1)) && empty($var2) && $x_var == true){}
```

However, the first 2 would need the `!` negation operator since you're checking if something is true.

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($var1)) && !empty($var2) && $x_var == true){}
```